# Reset row ids in relationship table mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with ids like 
1, 4, 8, 12.
I want to make it 1, 2, 3, 4. BUT I have another table making references to these id numbers. How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What problem are you trying to solve. The PK value has **no meaning** whatsoever. There is no need to change those values.

Comment: Only surrogate keys carry no meaning. But this is probably the case here (and modifying a primary key is always fishy, whether it is a surrogate key or not)

Comment: Don't try to have nice sequential numbers if you use MySQL's `auto_increment`. Just keep it like it is, don't try to "fix" it or anything like that, there are severe implications if you do that.

Comment: Thanks for the input. When I delete duplicates I have empty spots that i want to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the referencing table is InnoDB, alter the foreign key constraint and give it the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` property. Then all changes in the referenced field will be cascaded down to the referencing table.

[Here is a small example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90b78/1).